# Complicated Inequality Proof, Variables Subject To Constraint

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, contest-math, lagrange-multiplier

Let a, b, c be positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=1$. Prove that $\frac{a}{a^2 + b^3 + c^3} + \frac{b}{b^2 + c^3 + a^3} + \frac{c}{c^2 + a^3 + b^3} \le \frac{1}{5abc}$

This is a problem from RMO 2019. I tried using the method of Lagrange Multipliers, but it seems too lengthy. The solution on the site uses manipulative elementary proof.

Any non-elementary proofs or a straightforward method to solve these kind of problems?

Thank You.

Comment: There is a so high symmetry that the maximum of $\text{lhs - rhs}$ is clearly happening for $\cdots \text{???}$

Comment: Using that symmetry method, you will get 5 as an extrema. It's not solving the problem. I have tried it before. @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: I am sure that you did it ! It was just a mental calculation. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

**Too long for comment**:

Rewrite the inequality as:
$$
5\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2bc}{a^2+b^3+c^3}\leq 1,
$$
By AM-GM we have $$a^2bc \leq \frac{(1+a)^4}{256},$$ and by the power-means inequality we have
$$
\left(\frac{b^3+c^3}{2}\right)^{1/3}\geq\frac{b+c}{2}\implies b^3+c^3\geq\frac{(1-a)^3}{4},
$$
so
$$
5\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2bc}{a^2+b^3+c^3}\leq \frac{5}{64}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(1+a)^4}{4a^2+(1-a)^3}
$$

The RHS seems to be $\leq 1$, but I don't know how to prove it. The function $f(t)=\frac{(1+t)^4}{4t^2+(1-t)^3}$ is almost concave. Perhaps it can be approximated by some "nice" concave function.

Comment: Good use of AM GM and power means +1.  You can now show $g(t) = (1+t)^4/(4t^2+(1-t)^3)+128/25\cdot(1/3-t) \leqslant 64/15$ for $t\in (0, 1)$, so that's $g(a)+g(b)+g(c) \leqslant 64/5$.

Comment: @Macavity wow, great find! I will add this later in the answer, thanks. :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate how did you apply AMGM? @V.S.e.H.

Comment: @YatharthShrivastava It's just $(a^2bc)^{1/4} = (aabc)^{1/4} \leq (2a+b+c)/4 = (1+a)/4$

Comment: Okay. Thanks for clarifying.